# QTableWidget displaying rich text

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, richtext

I need to display rich text in a QTableWidget. Sometimes, the text has two or more colors. I'm  trying to doit via html tags. But QTableWidgetItem doesn't allow to insert html/rich text. I'm clueless to start planning a solution:

- sublclassing QTableWidgetItem? (is there a method responsable for "interpreting" text as plain/rich?)
- `myTableWidget->setCellWidget(row, col, new QTextEdit)` ?? This works, but I'm afraid the app will become more and more slow as multiple QTextEdits (may be 300 or more) are created.
- other suggestion?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Google for Andre Somers' "rich text delegate". YMMV

Comment: Interesting @peppe, I'll have to investigate what itemDelegates are all about... but it seems to be the solution